# Rank/Row Number Window Function in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, jupyter-notebook

I am a newcomer to Python and I am needing a solution for this example below, This is how my df looks like,

[image]

I need to return just two records one for ID_Number 207921021 and one for ID_Number 222037001. Using the below code I was able to get one record for ID_Number 222037001 based on max value of Score 1 and Score 2 when the Action is the same ('Invest' in this case),

```
Data=Data.groupby(['ID_Number','Action'])['Score_1','Score_2'].max().reset_index()
```

Below was my result,

[image]

Is there way to just to get one record for ID_Number 207921021 as well (Two separate values in the action column this time i.e. 'Use' and 'Avoid')? I have used Window Functions in SQL i.e using `QUALIFY RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY ID_number, Action ORDER BY Score_1,Score_2 DESC)=1` to get this done previously.

Is there a similar function in Python to do this?

Comment: If you want to partition by `ID_Number` and `Action` then you'll get 2 records for that `ID_Number` since there are 2 distinct actions. How do you plan on deciding which one? Your SQL would return two rows as well.

Comment: Which record under ID_Number 207921021 do you want to extract?  The one with a higher 'Score_2' value?

Comment: I would want want the one with the highest 'Score_2' value @Nev1111

Comment: @TomNash I would ideally want to use the action based on the highest 'Score_2' value

Comment: @Jude92 see updated result

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will pick one row per `ID_Number` with with sorting you defined.

```py
df.sort_values(by=['Score_2', 'Score_1'], ascending=[False, True]).groupby(['ID_Number']).head(1)
```

Output:

```py
    Action  ID_Number   Score_1     Score_2
3   Invest  222037001   9   0.4600
0   Use     207821021   7   0.4525
```